# How to perform smooth transition on largeTitleTextAttributes color attribute

Tags: ios, swift

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/9sOH5gF"><a href="//imgur.com/9sOH5gF"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I do want to perform a smooth transtion on the largeTitleTextAttributes color when the customer taps back on my swift application

I have tried to override the viewWillDisappear method on the sender view controller, setting the color I would like the largeTitleTextAttributes to have, and also overriding the viewWillAppear on the sender viewcontroller with no results.

on the receiver view controller

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {fatalError("Navigation controller does not exist.")}

        navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : FlatWhite()]
    }
```

on the sender view controller

```swift
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        //guard (navigationController?.navigationBar) != nil else {fatalError("Navigation controller does not exist.")}

        //updateNavBar(withHexCode: "1D9BF6")

        guard let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {fatalError("Navigation controller does not exist.")}

        guard let navBarColour = UIColor(hexString: "1D9BF6") else { fatalError()}

        navBar.barTintColor = navBarColour

        navBar.tintColor = FlatWhite()

        navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : FlatWhite()]
    }
```

Check the gif that I'm going to attach, but what I got is a "bad looking jump" on the color from back to white and I would like the color to be white when the view loads.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods for custom transitions. This WWDC should help too https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/ check the related video on that page if you need more infomration.

Comment: Thank you! I actually found a different solution, let me explain it: I used the https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition library that helps with clean transitions but additionally I had to mofidy the KMNavigationBarTransition .m files to handle the transitions for the largeTitleTextAttributes attributes. Then I made a clean build and it worked!

Comment: Nice, be careful that that library hasn't been updated for a few years. I know that implementing UINavigationControllerDelegate/ UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning is not just a few lines of code, but you can learn something and using a system framework means you don't have to worry about a bunch of third party code not being maintained and eventually breaking.